# How can I reset all the data on the Tensorboard in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I tried to delete the log file, but I can't even find the file I defined under the logdir path, how am I going to reset the graph every time I rerun my code? That confuses me a lot!

The graph are now stacked on previous graphs, which makes no sense to the final output.

Comment: You mean, you have multiple plots (e.g. the loss over time) superposed? This is caused by multiple event files.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is:

Every run gets a new named subdir of the the logdir path defined in the script as in:

```
/path-to-you-tb-dir/this_run_name/
```

Then start your code and (re)start tensorboard with first

```
fuser 6006/tcp -k
```

and then

```
tensorboard --logdir /path-to-you-tb-dir/
```

Now you'll have a sub dir for each run and a plot accordingly. You can delete selectively (by deleting the particular subdir)

Comment: How can I run fuser 6006/tcp -k? I am on Mac.

Comment: @xxx222 execute `lsof -i tcp:6006 | grep -v PID | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If old runs still show up even after deleting their log directory, try restarting tensorboard, and they should disappear.